# Can't replace string to multi-lined string with sed

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to replace a fixed parse ("replaceMe") in a text with multi-lined text with sed.
My bash script goes as follows:

```
content=$(awk'{print $5}' < data.txt | sort | uniq)
target=$(cat install.sh)
text=$(sed "s/replaceMe/$content/" <<< "$target")
echo "${text}"
```

If content contains one line only, replacing works, but if it contains sevrel lines I get:

```
sed:... untarminated `s' command
```

I read about "fetching" multi-lined content, but I couldn't find something about placing multi lined string

Comment: `sed` terminates commands with a newline. You can't reliably use multiline with sed.

Comment: By `awk'{print $5}' < data.txt | sort | uniq` - do you REALLY need to sort that input or are you just trying to get the unique values but the order doesn't matter?

Comment: @EdMorton Order does not matter... I read somewhere that you should 'sort' before 'uniq'

Comment: Yes `uniq` only works on contiguous identical values such as you'd get from sorted input but `sort | uniq` is equivalent to just `sort -u` and you don't need either to just get unique values when you're using awk (e.g. `awk '!seen[$0]++' file` alone outputs the unique values from `file`) which is why I was asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have more problems than that depending on the contents of `data.txt` since sed doesn't understand literal strings (see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001)). Just use awk which does:

```
text="$( awk -v old='replaceMe' '
    NR==FNR {
        if ( !seen[$5]++ ) {
            new = (NR>1 ? new ORS : "") $5
        }
        next
    }
    s = index($0,old) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old)) }
    { print }
' data.txt install.sh )"
```